# SharePoint Draft of a list Item

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am wondering if there is a way to make a "save draft" button on a SharePoint 2010 list. when it is clicked I want it to move the item to a "Your Drafts" List where only the user who created the draft can see their drafts. Then on the edit form of the "Your Drafts" list have a "publish" button that will add the item to the original list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking for a similar solution. The best I have found yet is to either store the draft items somewhere else as Nigel suggests, or store them in folders in the same list. Either way the permissions-aspect can get cumbersome.

A somewhat different solution is to cheat: Create a document library, and base all your content types on the document link (or folder?) content type. In this case all your items will be regarded as documents, and therefore you can use draft versions. But this will require you to handle the newform to avoid the OOTB document link form, and possibly have unwanted sideeffects in the ECB and ribbon menus.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing OTB in SharePoint that can provide this functionality. You could probably look at some ways of doing it with custom development.

If only the creator can see their own draft items it could get ugly really quick (particularly if there are a lot of users) because you'd need to look at unique, item-level permissions. The user's My Site could potentially be used as the draft location which would make permissions easier, but would mean having the items (the draft ones at least) distributed across all of those sites.